# spring boot rest API HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: spring-boot

```
@PostMapping(value ="/user", consumes={MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ApplicationUser createClient(@RequestBody @Valid ApplicationUserDto input,
                                    @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile logo) {
    return svc.registerNewClient(input, logo);
}
```

When I try to test it from swagger-ui,  `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=---------------------------158650901010513877241477242870;charset=UTF-8' not supported`

Am I missing something?

Because the api works fine as :

```
    @PostMapping(value ="/user")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ApplicationUser createClient(@RequestBody @Valid ApplicationUserDto input) {
        return svc.registerNewClient(input);
    }
```

or

```
@PostMapping(value ="/user")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ApplicationUser createClient(@RequestParam MultipartFile logo) {
    return svc.registerNewClient(logo);
}
```

Comment: The multipart file will be existed in the request body and the `@RequestBody` will read the entire body so you would get the wrong result.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: You may need to split it to two separate apis